# AngularJS regular lookup

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cordova

I have a question I tried googling but couldn't get what I was expecting. Hope people around here will make me clear.

Am working on AngularJS from last few months and now I have a situation where there is a list of data. This list is loaded via a server(PHP). 
Each list has a tracking image which changes according to the status set in the database.

Now I want this tracking image to change when the admin changes the status of that list in the database. 
Right now it happens when I reload the page or when I go back and come again on this listing page.

I know there is something called `$watch` and in js we have `setInterval`.
But is this a good idea to use `$watch` or setInterval as it will check continuously in the database for change. Am just wondering if this will lead to the crash or it will make my application to get slow.

Please note am developing a PhoneGap application using AngularJS.
Please throw your ideas it might be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is probably not the right place to answer your question but there is no problem in using `$watch` in AngularJS.

But, using `setInterval` and continuously polling your server will be expensive and is a waste of resource. You should probably go for the something called WebHooks.

Resources:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook
2. http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/automate-mobile-app-development/

Since you are developing a PhoneGap application, you can also use the Push Notification concept of Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to let the `server update your client`, without the client repeatedly asking for it, then you will need to use `websocket libraries`. If your server is not able to supply a websocket service, then i fear that doing a `$http.get` every certain timeperiod is your only option. But yes it sucks, because of the often unneccesary data travels.